# How to reuse an existing native view in a CustomRenderer (of a Xamarin.Forms.View)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, native, custom-renderer

I have CustomRenderer for a Xamarin.Forms.View which is for the moment implemented as an Android.Views.View. I'm using OnElementChanged to setup the element, which works great.

I work with a Pop / Push mechanism to navigate to a new page and return back to it later. CurrentView is the new (and current) Xamarin.Forms.View pushed onto the stack.

```
mainPage = new MainPage {Content = CurrentView};
app.MainPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
Stack.Push(CurrentView);
```

Therefore I'm storing an already visualized Xamarin.Forms.View temporarily on a Stack while it is not part of any of a page on screen, only the topmost View on the Stack is visible. Lateron I want to reuse this exact View (along with the existing native Android.Views.View pendant) but when I add it again to a page it is regarded as a new element in OnElementChanged (e.NewElement is set and this.Control is null), even if I set it via SetNativeControl in the custom renderer.

```
OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
{
    if ( this.Control == null && e.NewElement != null )
    {
        //always lands in here => regarded as a new element

        //create view    
        var nativeControl = ...

        this.SetNativeControl(nativeControl);
     }
}
```

Does anyone have any experience in reusing the native pendants to a Xamarin.Forms.View?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are trying to add the *same* Forms view *twice* into a view hierarchy? That's an unsupported use case.

Comment: No, it's like removing Xamarin.Forms.View from page and later adding the same Xamarin.Forms.View again to a page. And at that point it will not reuse the native pendant, but create a new one - the Xamarin.Forms.View is the same however (same HashCode).

Comment: I know it's 4 years ago, but was this ever solved? I'm facing this exact same issue...